# What is the main point of Active Patterns?

Tags: f#

When we pattern match on a value using [Active Patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/active-patterns), there is a "convert" function implicitly called. So instead of writing:

```
match value with
| Tag1 -> ...
| Tag2 -> ...
```

I can explicitly write:

```
match convert value with
| Tag1 -> ...
| Tag2 -> ...
```

This way, I don't have to use Active Patterns here. Of course, I have to explicitly call the `convert` function, and have to explicitly declare a union type. But those are minor things to me.

So what is the main point of Active Patterns?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The primary power of pattern matching is not the funny syntax. The primary power of patterns is that they can be *nested*.

Take a look at this:

```
match value with
| Foo (Bar, Baz [First 42; Second "hello!"]) -> "It's a thing"
| Qux [42; 42; 42] -> "Triple fourty-two"
| _ -> "No idea"
```

Assuming all capitalized words are active patterns, let's try to rewrite the first pattern in terms of calling `convert` explicitly:

```
match convertFoo value with
| Foo (x, y) -> 
    match convertBar x, convertBaz y with
    | (Bar, Baz [z1; z2]) ->
        match convertFirst z1, convertSecond z2 with
        | First 42, Second "hello!" -> "It's a thing"
```

Too long and convoluted? But wait, we didn't even get to write all the non-matching branches!

```
match convertFoo value with
| Foo (x, y) -> 
    match convertBar x, convertBaz y with
    | (Bar, Baz [z1; z2]) ->
        match convertFirst z1, convertSecond z2 with
        | First 42, Second "hello!" -> "It's a thing"
        | _ -> "No idea"
    | _ -> "No idea"
| Qux [42; 42; 42] -> "Triple fourty-two"
| _ -> "No idea"
```

See how the "No idea" branch is triplicated? Isn't copy&paste wonderful? :-)

---

Incidentally, this is why C#'s feeble attempt at what they have the audacity to call "pattern matching" isn't really pattern matching: it can't be nested, and therefore, as you very astutely observe, it is no better than just calling classifier functions.

Comment: Please include enough code to run the examples, so we can really get what you’re saying.  Thanks.